# How do i prevent elasticsearch's _analyze from interpretting yml

Tags: elasticsearch, yaml, elasticsearch-5

I'm trying to use the _analyze api with text that looks like this:

```
--- some -- text ---
```

This request works as expected:

```
curl localhost:9200/my_index/_analyze -d '--'
{"tokens":[]}
```

However, this one fails:

```
curl localhost:9200/medical_documents/_analyze -d '---'
---
error:
  root_cause:
  - type: "illegal_argument_exception"
    reason: "Malforrmed content, must start with an object"
  type: "illegal_argument_exception"
   reason: "Malforrmed content, must start with an object"
status: 400
```

Considering the formatting of the response, i assume that elasticsearch tried to parse the request as yaml and failed.

If that is the case, how can i disable yml parsing, or `_analyze` a text that starts with `---` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the yaml parser. The problem is that you are trying to create a type.
The following is incorrect
(will give you `Malforrmed content, must start with an object error`) 
`curl localhost:9200/my_index/medical_documents/_analyze -d '---'`
This will give you **no error**, but is incorrect. Because it will tell elastic to create a new type.
`curl localhost:9200/my_index/medical_documents/_analyze -d '{"analyzer" : "standard","text" : "this is a test"}'`

Analyzers are created **Index level**. verify with: 
`curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my_index/_settings'<br/>`

So the proper way is:
`curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my_index/_analyze' -d '{"analyzer" : "your_analyzer_name","text" : "----"}'`
Previously need to create the analyzer.